# Highlighting text content using the content from an another div

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to highlight the text content in paragraph using text content from an another div. So there is the "increase overall code" in the the first div. I want that these words from the main paragraph to be highlighted by using the first div. Thank you for the possibility to ask for help here!

```js
function highlight() {
  var htext = document.getElementById("torles");
  var inputText = document.getElementById("inputText");
  var innerHTML = inputText.innerHTML;
  var index = innerHTML.indexOf(text);
  if (index >= 0) {
    innerHTML = innerHTML.substring(0, index) + "<span class='highlight'>" + innerHTML.substring(index, index + text.length) + "</span>" + innerHTML.substring(index + text.length);
    innerHTML.innerHTML = innerHTML;
  }
}
```

```css
.highlight {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<html>

<body>
  <div class="col-md-10 bordered selectborder fragment" id="torles">increase overall coder
  </div>
  <button onclick="highlight()">Highlight</button>

  <div class="col-md-10 para bordered" id="inputText">
    <strong><p>Significantly Reduce Costs and Improve Quality with an Experienced, Professional Global Coding Solution. Health Information Management (HIM) Directors and CFOs are seeking innovative ways to reduce expenses, maintain DNFB goals, and increase overall coder quality.</p></strong>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, there were a couple things; but first, here's a working example.

```js
function highlight() {
  var text = document.getElementById("torles").textContent;//you want the text not the node
  var inputText = document.getElementById("inputText");
  var innerHTML = inputText.innerHTML;
  var index = innerHTML.indexOf(text);
  if (index >= 0) {
    innerHTML = innerHTML.substring(0, index) + "<span class='highlight'>" + innerHTML.substring(index, index + text.length) + "</span>" + innerHTML.substring(index + text.length);
    inputText.innerHTML = innerHTML;//this line was incorrect
  }
}
```

```css
.highlight {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<html>

<body>
  <div class="col-md-10 bordered selectborder fragment" id="torles">increase overall coder</div><!-- make sure there's no line break after "coder"-->
  <button onclick="highlight()">Highlight</button>

  <div class="col-md-10 para bordered" id="inputText">
    <strong><p>Significantly Reduce Costs and Improve Quality with an Experienced, Professional Global Coding Solution. Health Information Management (HIM) Directors and CFOs are seeking innovative ways to reduce expenses, maintain DNFB goals, and increase overall coder quality.</p></strong>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Anyway, there were three main things (and a typo). Firstly, you had a line break in your HTML after `increase overall coder`, and so it would try to find that string *with the line break* in the text, so it would just not find it.

Second, you mixed up what your variables actually mean; to start off, the `text` variable (which you misspelled as `htext`) was a node, not a string. Also, you tried to set the `innerHTML` of `innerHTML`, but your variable `innerHTML` was just a string. You want to set the `innerHTML` of the node (`inputText` in this case).

Comment: And can I improve it to use multiple times, on the same paragraph, but with another couple of words from an input in the same time? I mean:
ex. If I want to highlight the word "are", "and" separately from other two divs.

Comment: Yes you could, but I suppose it's better to try and figure that out yourself for a bit, and if you get stuck again, post it as a new question rather than changing this one